# python equivalent for RSA.SignData in .NET

Tags: python, rsa, digital-signature, pycrypto

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(PrivateKey);

string data = "SAMPLE TEXT.";

byte[] signedData = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
string signedString = Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);
```

The code above signs a string with a PrivateKey loaded from an xml.

Would you help me rewrite it in python?

I wrote this code myself but it produce a different signature!

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util.number import bytes_to_long, long_to_bytes
from hashlib import sha1
import base64

msg = "SAMPLE TEXT."
hashed = sha1(msg.encode('utf-8')).digest()
pubkey = RSA.construct((m,e))
encrypted = pubkey.encrypt(hashed, b'X')[0]
print("Signature: {0}".format(base64.b64encode(encrypted)))
```

Comment: I haven't found proper documentation of what `SignData(byte[], object)` does and looking into the reference source of .Net didn't answer this. I suspect it's a simple textbook RSA invocation, but I'm not sure. It can also be RSA signature with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or PSS padding.

Comment: The SignData method on RSACryptoServiceProvider which doesn't take an RSASignaturePadding does PKCS#1 v1.5 signature padding.  The sample here in python appears to encrypt, which may be using PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption padding (different beast) or raw (differenter beast); and it's using a public key operation whereas signing is a private key operation.

Comment: @bartonjs Thank you very much, such a useful comment, so I learned that encrypting is different from signing and some google taught me signing will be done using a private key. but still I don't get my lovely output so can you explain more about signature padding and how can I force pycrypto to work this way?

Comment: I wrote a new snippet you can see here https://pastebin.com/Gv2VY5Za, but it doesn't work fine yet ( the output differs from what C#.NET gives me )

Answer (score -1):

There is no builtin RSA library in Python, that I know of, but take a look at [this one (just named rsa)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa) which supports [signing](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#signing-and-verification).

```
# importing rsa
import rsa

# generating a key
(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(512)

# message
message = 'Go left at the blue tree'

# signing
signature = rsa.sign(message, privkey, 'SHA-1')

# verifying
rsa.verify(message, signature, pubkey) # True
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can use external libraries like _**PyCryto**_

Comment: Not quite a link-only answer, but you could provide more information. Consider describing the library so that, if the link becomes dead, a user can google using your description and find the new location of the library.

Comment: You'd better tell us more about that library. putting the link is not enough ! Also the op asked about rewriting the code in python like doing some math operations to generate ! anyhow the library you mentioned is not doing much !